# How to get the status bar height in iOS Extension

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplication, ios8-share-extension, share-extension

I can get the status bar from UIApplication in normal app by

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame
```

But we cannot access UIApplication from Extension.Is there a way to find get the statusbar in share?

Comment: why you want the status bar height anyway, it's always 20 in all the devices.

Comment: what kinda extension does it require to know about the status bar's frame?

Comment: I am using the height for custom animation for that viewcontroller.any way i found that there is no meaning in getting status bar from extension.hence i have to alter the animation thing.

Comment: kiran it's not 20 if the user is on a call.  and sometimes it's 0.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) to calculate layout frame.
eg,

```
viewController.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.minY
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate Option:**

If you're using a view controller with `NavigationBar`, you can consider its `y` position as the `StatusBar` height, in case `safeAreaLayoutGuide` and `window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height` options were not available or usable.

```
let statusBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y ?? 0
```